# Implementing the not operator when using the is keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, types, operators

Is there anyway to implement a not `!` operator in C# when using `is` keyword  , for example if I have a class named `Model` , I can check in a list of Items for what items are of type `Model` similar to  `Items.Where(x => x is Model)`

but what if I want to check for the items in the list that are NOT of type `Model` ?

Is there anyway to implement something like this,

`Items.Where(x => x is ! Model)` or `Items.Where(x => x isNot Model)`

one work around I found is

```
Items.Where(x => x.GetType().Name != "Model")
```

but is there any better way to implement this ?

Comment: Items.Where(x => !(x is Model))

Comment: `Items.Where(x => x.GetType().Name != "Model")` is not the direct opposite, as it won't handle inheritance. Go with what @AtK suggested.

Comment: understood , thank you @Atk for your support

Comment: You're Welcome. @LasseV.Karlsen gave a valid point as well.